# Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, matrix, typeerror, python-2.x

I'm going to do Matrix Addition on Python.(Not finish). But it shows an error.

```
m, n = (int(i) for i in raw_input().split())
a = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
b = [[0 for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
c = []
total = []

for i in range(m):
    x = raw_input()
    for j in range(n):
        value = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
    c[i][j] = a[i][j]
    #c.append(value)
print a
for i in c:
    print i
```

---

I want to input

3 3  <-- matrix dimensional m*n

1 2 3  >

3 2 1  > matrix A

1 3 2  >

1 1 1   >

1 1 1   > matrix B

1 1 1   >

and shows as

2 3 4 >

4 3 2 > matrix A + B

2 4 3 >

Comment: Try to change `value = [int(i) for i in x.split()]` to `value = [int(k) for k in x.split()]` ? You are using `i` in the for loop + in the list comprehension.

Comment: Since `0` is an immutable object, you can simplify to `a = [ [0]*m for j in range(n) ]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `i` in your outer `for` loop, and it is an int.  Then in the loop you have:

```
value = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
```

which makes `i` a string (which is what `split` returns).  Maybe you think there is some sort of scoping inside `[ ]`?  There isn't.  You have a name collision, change one of them.

Comment: +1 Note that Python 3 *does* create a new scope for comprehensions.

Comment: @chepner: well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

You are using same variable in inner for loop.

```
for i in range(m):
    x = raw_input()
    for j in range(n):
        # variable i is refering to outer loop
        value = [int(p) for p in x.split()]
    c[i][j] = a[i][j]
    #c.append(value)
print a
for i in c:
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the first two answers you'll have a problem with this statement:

```
c[i][j] = a[i][j]
```

When the loop starts `i` will be 0 and that's so far OK, but `c` is an empty list and has no iterable at the first position so `c[0][0]` will return an error.
Get rid of it and uncomment the following line:

```
#c.append(value)
```

EDIT:

Your code won't return what you want. You'd better make something like this to create a matrix with the given sides:

```
for i in range(m):
    d = []
    for j in range(n):
        x = raw_input()
        d.append(int(x))
     c.append(d)
```

If you have 3 for both `m` and `n`, then you will create matrix with sides 3 x 3 saved in the variable `c`.
In this way you don't have to split the user input. The user can give a number at a time. And you could even change the following line:

```
x = raw_input()
```

to:

```
x = raw_input("{0}. row, {1}. column: ".format(i+1, j+1))
```

Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
m, n = (int(i) for i in raw_input().split())
a = []
b = []
total = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]

for i in range(m):
    x = raw_input()
    for j in range(n):
        value = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
    a.append(value)
#print a


for i in range(m):
    x = raw_input()
    for j in range(n):
        value = [int(i) for i in x.split()]
    b.append(value)
#print b


for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        total[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j]


for i in total:
    print ' '.join(map(str, i))
time.sleep(2)
```

OK! I just figured it out! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can also hit this error if you declare an int and treat it like a dict

```
>>> a = []
>>> a['foo'] = 'bar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```