# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str (boolean convertion actually)

Tags: python, find, movie, review

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

documents=[(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)),category)
           for category in movie_reviews.categories()
           for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)
#print(documents[1])

all_words=[]

for w in movie_reviews.words():
    all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words=nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features=[]
    for w in word_features:
        features[w]= (w in words)

    return features

print((find_features(movie_reviews.words('neg/cv000_29416.txt'))))

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev,category) in documents]
```

---

After run,
I am getting the error

```
features[w]= (w in words)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Please help me to solve it...

Comment: `features` is supposed to be a list or a dict ?

Comment: features defined as a list just above, should be a dict to accept strings as "indexes"

Comment: Try declaring features as a dict
features = {} instead of features = []

Comment: Obviously a common error: [TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667531/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-python), [Python: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973413/python-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-str), [TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str on Python Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392119/typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-not-str-on-python-dictionary?rq=1),...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Only change that needs to be made is that `features` must be initialized to a `dict` (`{}`) rather than a `list` (`[]`) and then you could populate it's contents.

The `TypeError` was because `word_features` is a list of *strings* which you were trying to index using a list and lists can't have string indices.

```
features={}
for w in word_features:
    features[w] = (w in words)
```

Here, the elements present in `word_features` constitute the `keys` of dictionary, `features` holding boolean values, `True` based on whether the same element appears in `words` (which holds unique items due to calling of `set()`) and `False` for the vice-versa situation.

Comment: You should really add why, the change is so minimalistic, that no one will see it, if not already aware of the error. So better add some descriptive text.

Comment: @ Wolf: It's my bad. Was in a bit of haste and hence couldn't provide the needed explanation.

Comment: You emphasize *`dict`* and *`list`*, but this is not automatically synonymous to `{}` and `[]` for users which are new to python...

Answer (score 6):

You have tried to index a list `features` with a string and it is not possible with python. **List indices can only be integers**. What you need is a `dictionary`.

Try using a `defaultdict` meaning that even if a key is not found in the dictionary, instead of a `KeyError` being thrown, a new entry is created

```
from collections import defaultdict

features = defaultdict()
for w in word_features:
    features[w] = [w in words]
```

Comment: *`You can also try`* -- why "also", what alternative are you referencing? The simplest solution? ;)

Comment: The question was already answered before I could submit mine. So the word 'also'

Comment: Yes, but maybe the answer already given is poor (I really think that): throwing a piece of code and saying try this is not helpful, see my comment. I'd suggest to incorporate the obvious solution to the problem into your answer and say some more words about the mistake the OP made. Another alternative is to link to the answer (but I'm not really suggesting this here).